# Zeranoe ffmpeg not work with PHP

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I download and install [windows ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) in `C:/ffmpeg`. now i have this class for php ffmpeg without ext from [HERE](https://github.com/olaferlandsen/FFmpeg-PHP-Class). i check ffmpeg using cmd command this worked for me but ffmpeg not work using php class.

[PHP CLASS HERE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/olaferlandsen/FFmpeg-PHP-Class/master/src/ffmpeg.class.php)

PHP Code:

```
<?php
/**
*   include FFmpeg class
**/
include DIRNAME(DIRNAME(__FILE__)).'/src/ffmpeg.class.php';

/**
*   get options from database
**/
$options = array(
    'duration'  =>  99,
    'position'  =>  0,
    'itsoffset' =>  2,
);
/**
*   Create command
*/
$FFmpeg = new FFmpeg( "C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" );
$FFmpeg->input( 'C:\xampp\htdocs\video\ff\examples\original.avi' );

$FFmpeg->transpose( 0 )->vflip()->grayScale()->vcodec('h264')->frameRate('30000/1001');
$FFmpeg->acodec( 'aac' )->audioBitrate( '192k' );
foreach( $options AS $option => $values )
{
    $FFmpeg->call( $option , $values );
}
$FFmpeg->output( 'C:\xampp\htdocs\video\ff\examples\new.mp4' , 'mp4' );
print($FFmpeg->command);
?>
```

print command :

```
C:fmpeg\binfmpeg.exe -y -i C:\xampp\htdocs\video\ff\examples\original.avi -vf transpose=0,vflip -pix_fmt gray -vcodec h264 -r 30000/1001 -acodec aac -ab 192k -t 99 -ss 0 -itsoffset 2 -f mp4 C:\xampp\htdocs\video\ff\examples\new.mp4 2<&1
```

This Not Convert Video For Me. How Do i can fix this? And How Do i can check ffmpeg worked with php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change and replace `\` with `\\` like this:

$FFmpeg = new FFmpeg( "C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" );

To :

$FFmpeg = new FFmpeg( "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe" );

Comment: Oh Yes. This worked and convert video, But new file size is `0 kb`.